# how to calculate the average shortest path length in a multi-directed graph with several node not connected?

Tags: python, networkx

I'd like to calculate the `average_shortest_path_length` in my multi-directed graph but there is a node not connected with other nodes

for example I have a network with nodes and edges as below:

```
lst_nodes=[2782, 27118, 28931, 28936, 43162, 28770, 48325, 33783]

lst_edge = [(28931, 28936L), (28931, 27118L), (28931, 27118L), (28931, 33783L), (48325, 28936L), (28936, 43162L),
            (28936, 48325L), (27118, 28936L), (27118, 28936L), (27118, 48325L), (43162, 48325L), (2782, 28931L),
            (2782, 48325L), (2782, 48325L), (2782, 27118L), (2782, 33783L)]

MDG = nx.MultiDiGraph()
MDG.add_nodes_from(lst_nodes)
MDG.add_edges_from(lst_edge)

print 'avg shortest path length:', nx.average_shortest_path_length(MDG)
```

[image: figure_1-1.png]

it will ends up with an exception like

`networkx.exception.NetworkXError: Graph is not connected.`

but according to the notes in [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.average_shortest_path_length.html?highlight=average%20path%20length#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.average_shortest_path_length)

> For disconnected graphs you can compute the average shortest path length for each component: >>> G=nx.Graph([(1,2),(3,4)]) >>> for g in nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G): ... print(nx.average_shortest_path_length(g)) 1.0 1.0

it should work with components, so I try the code before

```
for g in nx.connected_component_subgraphs(MDG):
    print nx.average_shortest_path_length(g)
```

but ends up with an exception like
`networkx.exception.NetworkXNotImplemented: not implemented for directed type`
however if I remove the single node from the network,I can compute the average shortest path length for the network, so I wonder how I can calculate the average shortest path length in a multi-directed graph with several node not connected?

Comment: You can convert each of the components to an undirected graph: `for g in nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G): F=nx.Graph(g); ...`

Comment: @DYZ well, that's not correct, first of all, the average shortest path length for the directed graph and un-directed graph is different, and I tried your solution,it will ends up with a new exception `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero` since there is a single node in the network. thanks anyway

Comment: You are right, the average shortest path differs for digraphs and undirected graphs. But `nx.average_shortest_path_length` works only with undirected graphs (that's why it raises the exception), so I guess you don't have a choice. You can, of course, calculate `nx.shortest_path_length` and take the average.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I think that `nx.shortest_path_length` is the most reasonable solution:

```
import statistics
from itertools import chain
# This includes the isolated node!
path_lengths = (x.values() for x in nx.shortest_path_length(MDG).values())
statistics.mean(chain.from_iterable(path_lengths))
# 1
```

Comment: thank you @DYZ , but  according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_path_length), the average shortest path length is not counted as the simple mean value,but I have no idea if I should divide by the total number of nodes(`/8*(8-1)`) or just the number of nodes in the components(`/7*(7-1)`) while the latter got a result of 2/3 and I find if I consider it as an un-directed graph,the calculate should divide by the number of nodes in the components which got a result of about 1.47 similar to the result in `Gephi`